# How do I make a sine graph in Python that has adjustable values for A B C and D in the equation y=Asin(B*(X-C)+D? Beginner programmer :v

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


A = 2 
B = 2 
C = 3
D = 4
sample = 16
x = np.arange(sample)
y = (A*np.sin(B*(x-C))+D) 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('sample(n)')
plt.show()
```

the y= part is the equation the A B C D values are on top. whenever I try to graph this it comes out wrong

Comment: what do you mean it comes out wrong?

Comment: as in its supposed to look like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2sin%282x-3%29%2B4

Comment: you should `print x` ... those are the only values of X that will be calculated ...if you want smaller increments `arange(start,stop,step_size)` should allow you to get smaller step sizes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly consider increasing your sample size or decreasing the step. If that function looks different it's because your `x` values are too sparse.

Possibly `np.arrange(0,16,.1)` or even .01 if needed.

Comment: yeah this is actually what I suspect his problem is ... +1 for answering his intended question :P

Answer (score 0):

lets start with `x=0`

```
A*sin(B*(x-C))+D = 2 * sin(2*(0-3))+4
= 2 * sin(2*-3) + 4 = 2*sin(-6)+4
= 2*0.27941549819892586+4 = 4.5588309963978517
```

which just happens to be exactly the same as the y[0] value you calculated above...

that seems like it is calculating exactly what you asked it for ...

Comment: i actually wanted this y=2sin(2x-3)+4

Comment: well then why did you not just write `A*np.sin(B*x-C) +D` .. if you group `(x-C)` then that will get done before the multiplication ...